# How to Find the sum of each row in a 2d array in JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

My Table model extends AbstractTableModel. In it, I am trying to use the last column of each row to hold the sum of each row. In my getValueAt() method of the TableModel class, I have the following code

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
    int sum;
    if(col==data[row].length-1){

        for(int k=0; k<data.length;k++){
            sum=0;
            for(int l=0; l<data[k].length;l++){
                sum+=(Integer)getValueAt(k,l);
            }
                data[k][30]=sum;    
        }
    }
    return data[row][col];
}
```

Whenever I run the code above, StackOverflow and other type of errors in the console are displayed. I cant find out the bug in this code. Besides, I am clueless if this code will sum the total of each row in the array. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Unless the data is being dynamically updated, it would be better to pre-calculate this value as soon as possible, even then, unless it's being changed a lot, I would cache the result as soon as you can.

Comment: logics is wrong, everything should be invoked from setValueAt, is required to block columnReordering and RowSorter or is required to convert index from view to Model

Comment: I am new to this forum and dindt have any idea about SSCCE rules. From now on, However, I will abide by the rules. Thanks for reminding @Andrew Thompson

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/626475/GUI/java/sum-total-row-JTable#2865860)

Comment: is crossposting against forum rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as below:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
    int sum;
    if(col==data[row].length-1){
        sum=0;
        for(int l=0; l<data[row-1].length;l++){
            sum+=(Integer)data[row-1][l];
                    }
            data[row-1][30]=sum;    
        }
    }
    return data[row][col];
}
```

since you were overriding the getValueAt method and inside you that method you are again calling `getValueAt()`. Due to recursion you are getting stackoverflow and other error.